# Humanized messages placement

Tags: interaction-design

For [humanized message](https://code.google.com/p/humanmsg/) placement what is considered to be the best placement? Upper right side of screen, or upper left side of screen? The person that I work for said that there was a study on humanized message placement and the study's conclusion said that the HM should be on the LEFT. To me, that doesn't seem correct.

Where should humanized messages be placed?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Humanized Messages is just a jQuery plugin for displaying unobrtrustive  notifications. I doubt there are any usability studies on that plugin specifically - unless your employer can provide a reference? Are you looking for guidance on where notifications should appear more generally?

Answer (score 2):

Similar software puts the notifications in the **top-right** of the screen.

Examples include Apple's Notification Center, [Growl](http://growl.info/) for Windows and OSX, and the one Chrome uses whenever I play songs in Google Music.

This seems to be industry standard for non-intrusive notifications.

If you're looking for a bigger punch, put them straight in the middle of the screen rather than a corner.

Comment: The right corner tends to be the least intrusive position (compared to center & left) for these messages if you take into account of the typical F-shape scanning pattern.